# Mongodb: How to translate values?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following example collection of documents:

```
{ page: 'a' }, { page: 'c' }, { page: 'b' }
```

And the following example translation map (this would contain about 20 entries in reality):

```
{ 'a': 'a-x', 'c': 'c-3' }
```

How do I select and update all documents in a collection to get

```
{ page: 'a-x' }, { page: 'b' }, { page: 'c-3' } ]
```

Is it possible to do it using aggregation or updateMany?

Comment: its possible using aggregate, however this will not update the documents you will have to preform another query with the results which requires some code. and in that case you might as well just build a condition dynamically using code and call updateMany. if you are interested i can write a code sample

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `updateMany` to achieve this you must do it in different queries.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
     { "page": "a" },
     { $set: { "page" : "a-x" }
);

db.collection.updateMany(
     { "page": "c" },
     { $set: { "page" : "c-3" }
);
```

Otherwise you could do it in a single one, using the `aggregation`.
Check the aggretate documentation in the mongoDb website:
[Aggregate documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)

Comment: Thanks, the reason for using the translation map is to avoid multiple queries. I thought it would be possible using the $let aggregation command somehow. I'm also trying to avoid map/reduce as it's much slower and it's a live database with lots of users.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      a: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ["$page", "a"] },
          then: { $concat: ["$page", "-x"] },
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      },
      c: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ["$page", "c"] },
          then: { $concat: ["$page", "-3"] },
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```